# Change the background for all `li` (hover)

Tags: css

I want to change the background for all `li` that has `div` that has `<a class="wasAdRead"`.

```
<li>
    <div class="notification_div" style="padding-top: 6px;">
         <a class="wasAdRead" style="cursor:pointer;">Remind me later</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

I tried:

```
#notification-list li[div[.wasAdRead]]:hover
{
    background: white;
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You can't do it only with the current CSS (3). You can do it with JS, or wait to CSS 4 :)

Comment: I don't think you can. You're trying tot select the parent element of `.notification_div`, which isn't possible with pure CSS (with JS you can). Also check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/1930721

Comment: Do your li's contain other stuff? if not... why not just put the wasAdRead class into the li element ? or you could change the div's background color, it's not the li itself but as an block element it would fill the whole li's area (unless it has some padding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with just CSS (in 2013 anyway). You need to do this with javascript (by select every `<li>` and check their content). In jQuery, it gives something like:

```
$("a.wasAdRead").parents('li').css("background-color", "white");
```

... or you can wait for CSS4 (good luck, you can wait many years for browser supports...)

You can check this post which is about your problem: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector/1014958#1014958)

Answer (score 1):

Not possible in CSS, you can do that with JS only. Also you can try this alternative solution.

```
.notification_div a.wasAdRead{
   display:block;
   padding-top:6px;
   cursor: pointer;
   background-color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are this you are looking for

```
li > .notification_div > .wasAdRead:hover{
   display:block;
   padding-top:6px;
   cursor: pointer;
   background-color:red;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyA4a/)